# How to specify a Academic License in a Setup installers License field

Tags: deployment, computer-science, software-distribution

I have done one useful tool for architecture modeling in software engineering area, I have done deployment/setup for it, I need a suggestion: what can I write in the field "License" because here I need to put something general, :
Is :"This tools is used for academic purpose only" ? please give me some suggestion for that..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> what can I write in the field "License" because here I need to put
>   something general, : Is :"This tools is used for academic purpose
>   only"

For the "License" field you should put **Academic Free License**  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_Free_License

*ps Question Title's should reflect Question, I edited it accordingly.*